# Using spatialite with xerial/sqlite-jdbc on MacOS

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, spatialite, geopackage

I'm having some problems loading the spatialite extension in Java to read a GeoPackage, I have the following snippet:

```
import org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DatabaseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, URISyntaxException {
        URI databaseURI = DatabaseTest.class.getResource("/database.gpkg").toURI();
        String databaseURL = String.format("jdbc:sqlite:%s", databaseURI);
        SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
        config.enableLoadExtension(true);
        Connection connection = config.createConnection(databaseURL);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        boolean success = statement.execute("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')");
        System.out.println(success);
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }

}
```

This results in a `[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (dlopen(mod_spatialite.dylib, 10): image not found)`

If I change to

```
boolean success = statement.execute("SELECT load_extension('/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite')");
```

It results in `Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)`

Is there anything I am missing. I have installed `sqlite3` and `spatialite` using Homebrew, and that is the version of `spatialite` I am trying to use.